# Pandas: Merge parquet files with different column dtypes - write parquet with predefined schema?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd need to export very large DB tables to s3.
I'm doing so by parallelising pandas read_sql (with processpool), and using my table's primary key id to generate a range to select for each worker. - This results in very fast exports.

```
process 1: id between 1 and 9   -> 1.pq
process 2: id between 10 and 19 -> 2.pq
process 3: id between 20 and 29 -> 3.pq
```

The resulting dataframe get's written by each worker to the same folder.

The problem lies in my data: Some of the columns i have are not always filled (e.g. Deleted? null vs 1) - so some of my parquets will have the deleted column datatype as null others as Int64.

When i'm trying to read the dataset from either pyarrow, fastparquet or pyspark i get various errors regarding the schema.

I had tried researching into arrow tables, but so far only found a way to define a schema for validation only.

Reproduction:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

data=pd.DataFrame([[1,None],[1,None]])
data2=pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,1]])
data.columns = data.columns.astype(str) ## Parquet requires string column names
data2.columns = data2.columns.astype(str)
data.to_parquet('./outputs/1.pq')
data2.to_parquet('./outputs/2.pq')
pq.ParquetDataset('./outputs')
```

I'd expect it to infer that my column '1' is int, but it get's a conflict. I tried with disabling schema_validation, but that just hides the issue until i actually process it.

```
ValueError: Schema in ../outputs/2.pq was different. 
0: int64
1: int64
metadata
--------
{b'pandas': b'{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "'
            b'stop": 2, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "field_'
            b'name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "'
            b'metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "0", "f'
            b'ield_name": "0", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", '
            b'"metadata": null}, {"name": "1", "field_name": "1", "pandas_type'
            b'": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}], "creator"'
            b': {"library": "pyarrow", "version": "0.14.0"}, "pandas_version":'
            b' "0.24.2"}'}

vs

0: int64
1: null
metadata
--------
{b'pandas': b'{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "'
            b'stop": 2, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "field_'
            b'name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "'
            b'metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "0", "f'
            b'ield_name": "0", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", '
            b'"metadata": null}, {"name": "1", "field_name": "1", "pandas_type'
            b'": "empty", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}], "creator'
            b'": {"library": "pyarrow", "version": "0.14.0"}, "pandas_version"'
            b': "0.24.2"}'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own customized 'pyarrow schema' and cast each pyarrow table with your schema.

```
  import pyarrow as pa
    import pyarrow.parquet as pq
    def merge_small_parquet_files(small_files, result_file):
        pqwriter = None
        for small_file in small_files:
            table = pq.read_table(small_file)
            pyarrow_schema = get_pyarrow_schema()
            if not pqwriter:
                pqwriter = pq.ParquetWriter(result_file,
                                        schema=pyarrow_schema,
                                        compression='GZIP',
                                        coerce_timestamps='ms', allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
                table = table.cast(pyarrow_schema)
                pqwriter.write_table(table)
                table = None
                del table
            if pqwriter:
                pqwriter.close()

    def get_pyarrow_schema():
        fields = []
        fields.append(pa.field('first_name', pa.string()))
        fields.append(pa.field('last_name', pa.string()))
        fields.append(pa.field('Id', pa.float64()))
        fields.append(pa.field('Salary', pa.float64()))
        fields.append(pa.field('Time', pa.timestamp('ms')))
        pyarrow_schema = pa.schema(fields)
        return pyarrow_schema
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        small_files = ['file1.parquet', 'file2.parquet', 'file3.parquet', 'file4.parquet']
        result_file = 'large.parquet'
        merge_small_parquet_files(small_files, result_file)
```